# TpuClient.send_transaction gets dropped occasionally

Tags: rust, solana-sdk

I want to send a transaction using the following code:

```
let blockhash = tpu_client.rpc_client().get_latest_blockhash().unwrap();

let tx = Transaction::new_signed_with_payer(
    &instructions,
    Some(&wallet.pubkey()),
    &[&wallet],
    blockhash,
);

let sx = tpu_client.send_transaction(
    &transaction
);
```

In probably 90% of the cases my transaction gets dropped. Does someone has an idea what could cause this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is totally normal unfortunately. If you're using the TPU client directly, then you're sending the transactions directly to the leader to try and get your transaction included in the block.

Your TPU client is running from an unknown / unstaked sender, and validators reserve a very small number of connections for unstaked senders. To successfully land your transaction, you'll likely need to retry sending your transaction (ideally, without re-signing).

The TPU client exposes a way to do this easily: `TpuClient::send_and_confirm_messages_with_spinner` https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/3284d34e041f737ddb0b946d0695d9c6ada0fc71/tpu-client/src/tpu_client.rs#L163